# Passing Arrays to a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

What is the best, most preferable (and, if possible, efficient) way to pass an array of strings from a .NET application to a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure?

1) Pass the array of strings as a comma- or semicolon-delimited string and parse it into a temporary table?

2) Pass the array as XML and use SQL Server 2005 methods to parse it into a temporary table?

3) Write an ancilliary stored procedure to deal with each string individually and having .NET calling it for every element in the array?

4) Other... What?

I would say solution 2) is the most elegant one, but it is certainly not the most efficient... Is it?

Comment: how big should be array -  10 lines or 1mln?

Comment: Under normal circunstances it will be small, but I cannot bound it.

Comment: Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005. http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this article.

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

The other related articles:
[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

**Edit:**
Sorry I did not realized that it is already mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your requirements.

1. In case I am importing then pass the **XML** and use **SQL Server 2005** methods to parse it into a temporary table
2. If the records are not in bulk, I can use **semicolon-delimited** string.
3. If it is like you have some enumeration values like filtering the records on the basis of multiple status then I can use **In**

[Good and Bad points about array passing](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Hope this will help you. :)